# Setting the context for cloth bake

Tags: python, baking, cloth-simulation

I'm having trouble using `bpy.ops.ptcache.bake()`.

I get the error message `bpy.ops.ptcache.bake.poll() failed, context is incorrect` no matter what I set the context to. I tried using `bpy.context.area.type="PROPERTIES"` but I still get the same error.

How can I set the context in order to bake a cloth simulation in a script?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/baking-smoke-on-headless-machine?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248275/599) for the operator to work. [similar to this answer on baking fluid or smoke](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4963/599), you can bake the cloth cache for every object in the file which has a cloth modifier like this:

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for object in scene.objects:
        for modifier in object.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'CLOTH':
                with bpy.context.temp_override(scene=scene,
                                               active_object=object,
                                               point_cache=modifier.point_cache):
                    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(bake=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed it for some reason. What should I replace `domain_settings.point_cache` with? since a cloth has no domain (I took out that last If, btw, for the same reason.

Comment: Ok, so I tried using only `modifier.point_cache`, but now it starts baking, then gives me the same error as before, only before it it says things like `PyContext 'window' not found` or `PyContext 'region' not found`. Any tips?

Comment: @Shef It works for me. AFAIK those PyContext messages are just warnings, including the context override for those is not actually necessary in this case.

Comment: *ptcache.bake(override* is no longer supported in v3.4.  Can someone update this answer?  thx

Comment: @james_t I've updated my answer, thanks for the heads up!