# 2.77 Headless Smoke Baking

Tags: python, scripting

I just downloaded 2.77 yesterday and am trying to bake a simple Cycles smoke scene composed of a box domain, sphere flow, and two obstacles. Note that I have a peculiar setup; I build my .blends on a MacBook and then send the files down to a headless Linux box (w/ i7 and GTX 970; I use the i7 to bake) in my basement. In the past, I have used the python script and CLI arguments described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/baking-smoke-on-headless-machine), but now I get an error. It starts out like it's supposed to with the usual preamble, but then when it starts to load the noise tile files, it `Blender quit`s. I am also familiar with [Fluid Baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/724/bake-fluid-simulation-via-cli-or-python/728#728) and [Dynamic Paint baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6746/how-to-bake-dynamic-paint-surfaces-headlessly), if that influences your answer.

I know 2.77 is a huge update and now allows smoke to be rendered on the GPU. Could something have been tweaked that renders the aforementioned script inert? If that has been done, is there a new script that could be devised that would work? All help welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: When you say blender quits - does it say it's done or does it crash saying segmentation fault or similar? Are you setting FFT noise on the mac and the linux version is built without fft support? The cycles smoke rendering support isn't going to effect the baking process - baking is generating the data that gets sent to cycles.

Comment: No, it was Wavelet. Thanks for letting me know, though. Blender starts up fine and then it spits out "Blender quit." As I said, the process is headless and from the command line, which is UI-less. Blender can only crash through words, not pictures, and I have yet to witness what that would look like. I do appreciate your reply and would appreciate anything else you stumble across. @sambler