# Blender 2.77 renders smoke\fire domain solid black on GPU (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation, gpu

I have just updated to 2.77 version and was very exited about using GPU for rendering fire.

When I tried to render the test scene I got this:

[image: GPU render]

Though it should look like this (rendered on CPU):

[image: CPU render]

Blender is rendering domain solid black for some reason.
I got the following configuration:

AMD Radeon R280x (3Gb)

OpenCL Version
2.0.4.0

Comment: AMD Cards might still have some driver issues and are not fully supported yet as fas as I know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of writing, smoke/fire is still [currently only supported on CUDA/Nvidia cards](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html).

[image]

Comment: I asked a question on 2.77 smoke and fire recently, too, that related to your answer on a python script to bake smoke. I use that script, but it stopped working when I upgraded to 2.77. Could you please look at my question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49591/2-77-headless-smoke-baking Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a bug i think , i have a gpu cuda nvidia card, and the render with smoke/fire works fine, IF i only have one smoke domain in the scene, if I add 2 or three they wont render, only the first one. switch to cpu and all render.