# Blender VSE - import multiple rendered PNG frames?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, video

I usually use the Blender VSE for my normal video editing (for lack of After Effects).

I also usually render directly into AVI format, not PNG sequences of frames. I would however like to move to PNG sequences, because it's a lot easier to sort out any mistakes and to edit that way.

I would therefore like to load the sequences I render into the VSE quickly and easily (30fps) - which would normally require tweaking of every frame because they normally when added add an image strip which is 25 frames long (and I want each frame to be 1 frame long) - I can also only add one frame at a time.

How can I load a frame sequence into the VSE?

Comment: When you choose Add > Image, then select all frame in a folder (by hitting 'A'), it doesn't work ?

Comment: @Polosson Didn't try that xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select multiple Images in the File Browser while adding an Image Strip, you will get one Image Strip which can be scrubbed along through all your frames. Make sure to set up your Project frame rate properly before.

[image: Select multiple Images]

You can de-/select all Images in a folder by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>. Or you can select the first, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the <kbd>Down-Arrow</kbd> until all of your Image files are selected. This works over multiple columns in the File Browser if applicable.

Comment: @Samoth Please read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments

Comment: @poor: I did. If Polosson might post his point as an answer I would delete mine if that makes you SE folks happy. But I think it's fair to get some reputation for validating a method (which I thought of without reading his comment before) and elaborating around a bit too provide a neat answer. I took some time to create a PNG sequence, make that screenshot and validate how this works.

Comment: @poor: btw: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50241/blender-2-77-renders-smoke-fire-domain-solid-black-on-gpu-cycles#comment85660_50241 ;-)