# how to render animation in background on mac

Tags: rendering

i try to render my animation in background with this command:

`blender -b /Users/cd/Downloads/name.blend -x 1 -o // -a`

Unfortunately it renders just a still image as animation. so it is a .mov file, but no animation at all.

the animation has some physics in it -> maybe ...do i have to bake it first!?

If i render it manually in Blender it is an animation. What am i missing here?

Comment: If you go this route, I'd recommend render to an image sequence in the first place and then compile the sequence into whatever you need using ffmpeg.

Comment: ok, thanks, i try

Comment: unfortunately it does not help....it renders to a specific frame, but then it stops :(

Comment: Just add `-a` eg. `blender -b file.blend -a`, see: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

Comment: i have a -a at the end.....see my question...i got lots of images...but they are all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i baked the dynamics and then it works...but i think this is a bad solution, if i first have to bake it in blender and then i call the animation process in terminal....would be better if i could bake it in the terminal too...

but now i found this answers, which hopefully helps me a lot...

[Baking smoke on headless machine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/baking-smoke-on-headless-machine)