# Baking particles from command line

Tags: python, particles, baking, command-line

I am trying to bake particle systems from the command line. I saw this: [Baking smoke on headless machine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/baking-smoke-on-headless-machine) and I have been playing around with it, but I can't seem to get it to work for particles. I'm sure there is a way, but I just suck with coding like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/bake-all-dynamics-from-command-line/519419/7) thread which had [this code](https://github.com/ichlubna/blenderScripts/blob/master/MISC/bakeAll.py) in it. It works perfectly fine!!

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for object in scene.objects:
        for modifier in object.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'FLUID':
                if modifier.fluid_type == 'DOMAIN':
                    print("Baking fluid")
                    object.select_set(True)
                    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object
                    bpy.ops.fluid.bake_data()
            elif modifier.type == 'CLOTH':
                print("Baking cloth")
                override = {'scene': scene, 'active_object': object, 'point_cache': modifier.point_cache}
                bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake(override)
                bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=True)
            elif modifier.type == 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM':
                print("Baking particles")
                override = {'scene': scene, 'active_object': object, 'point_cache': modifier.particle_system.point_cache}
                bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake(override)
                bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=True)
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

As you can see, this script bakes fluid, particles, and cloth. To use it, just past the code into a file, save the file as a .py python file, and then in the Blender directory type blender -b "path to .blend file" -P "path to .py file" and Blender will bake it! I hope this helps.