# How to bake fluid and render at once

Tags: rendering, baking, fluid-simulation

I am working on some blender projects with fluid and so I wonder how can I make my computer bake fluid and render with only one click. For now I always baked fluid and then clicked again to render. Unfortunately I can't do that if I am sleeping or if I'm in school. What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like a bit of python is what you're after. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17839/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/724/599