# Limit Blender RAM usage?

Tags: memory-management

So Blender started crashing whenever I bake fluid for no reason (I mean no reason, discussion [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53988/blender-crashes-when-baking-fluid?noredirect=1#comment92578_53988)). I'm thinking maybe reducing the amount of RAM it uses could help, but I can't figure out how to reduce it.

Comment: First you should find if memory limits are the cause before asking this question.

Comment: @ideasman42 I'm almost certain they are because in Task Manager blender uses like 6GB of RAM then it crashes once there isn't any left.

Comment: Could you run Blender from a terminal and see what output you get? - https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/command_line.html Typically errors are printed before crashing.

Comment: @ideasman42 Already tried it, but no errors show up because blender doesn't just crash, my whole computer does and I have to restart.

Comment: do have swap enabled ? it's very slow but can help when there isn't enough space in RAM.

Comment: @root How do I check?

Comment: The task manager should have that information

Comment: I think this a good question, although may not be written in the best way. It's interesting to know if it can be limited so instead of crashing because it doesn't have enough memory it tells that the operation can't be done (adding a new node, backing, rendering, etc) but it doesn't crash. However, I suppose it's difficult to implement.

Answer (score -2):

*File > User Preferences > System > Middle Column at the Bottom (Sequencer / Clip Editor:)* and reduce the *Memory Cache Limit:* value (I believe it's in Kb, but you would have to check that).

[image]

Comment: Already tried, apparently that only limits RAM for the sequence and clip editors, my problem is baking fluid