# baking fluids, then exporting/re-importing as shape keys, or object meshes?

Tags: baking

Recently found out apparently I have to "bake" an animation that uses fluids, before I can actually render it. However, I need to have the 'baked' fluids built into the blender file, but it doesn't seem to be a way to do that (I am using version 2.79).

Google searching/etc/etc - some people seem to give a 'hint' as to a workaround - which somehow involves exporting the fluid animation into something called shape keys for the vertices of the fluid animation - OR - exporting each frame as a new mesh object, then re-importing it - and then rendering that. However, since it is just a 'hint' - I don't exactly get how I would do that (and I've tried various things).

How would I accomplish this? I am including a very basic blender example file where I have a domain for the fluid, and then smoke fluid on a cube mesh.

Thanks very much!

[image]

Comment: For fluids, look into alembic Caches. You can export your simulation as. abc sequence and import them with a geometry cache modifyer on a proxy object (a cube for example).

Comment: Thanks - I actually was - but don't "get" how to do that (in some ways I am still very new to blender). Could you please provide a step by step example? I see the .abc export sequence in the file->export, but don't get exactly what/how I am supposed to export. Using the example .blend file I have, could you help me? Thanks very much!

Comment: pps, been trying to play around with this, and still can't figure it out. I bake the fluid dynamics, select the cube, export to .abc, then I add another cube to the scene, select it, select the modifer (mesh cache sequence modifier - since mesh cache only seems to accept .mdd or .pc2 files),  - so I use the mesh cache sequence modifer, but if I click 'apply', I get an error saying "Modifier is disabled. Skipping Apply", so assuming that doesn't work)... any ideas on how to get it to work? thanks!

Comment: You only need to export the fluid sim if you want to use it outside of blender. You can automate the [fluid bake with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/724/935), once it is baked blender will use the cached sim data when rendering.

Comment: thanks. I figured it out. none of the answers really answered what I needed to do, but I figured it out on my own.