# How to free a fluid bake on the commandline?

Tags: python, baking, fluid-simulation, command-line

I want to rerun the fluid bake. I'm using the code at https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/311453/158745 to bake the fluid, which seems to work.

I try a variation on this code, to free the fluid:

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    # print('scene', scene)
    for object in scene.objects:
        # print('object', object)
        for modifier in object.modifiers:
            # print('modifier', modifier, 'modifier_type', modifier.type)
            if modifier.type == 'FLUID':
                # print('modifier.fluid_type', modifier.fluid_type)
                if modifier.fluid_type == 'DOMAIN':
                    print('freeing...')
                    object.select_set(True)
                    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object
                    bpy.ops.fluid.free_all()

bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

This technically succeeds in freeing the fluid bake. However, re-running the commandline fluid bake, does not error, but the fluid renders as unbaked, ie we just see the entire domain, rather than the fluid.

How to free a fluid bake in a way taht rebaking works ok?

(Alterantively, how to run a fluid bake, from commandline, overwrtiing any existing bake?)

(PS if I try to free the fluid and rebake, in the same loop, then the script crashes, which is why I split it into two scripts)

(removing the cache_fluid folder, then rerunning fluid bake also leads to same result: fluid is no longer baked, cannot re-bake)

(Note that the function above seems to work ok on Mac, just not in my cloud Ubuntu instance)